# Ratio of the Volume of n-spherical cap to the volume of n-sphere

Tags: geometry, volume, spherical-geometry

Assume an n-dimensional sphere with radius $R$ and volume $V^{(n)}_s$. Also assume a corresponding  n-spherical cap with height $h$ and volume $V^{(n)}_c$. what is the ratio of two volumes?
$$\frac{V^{(n)}_c}{V^{(n)}_s}=?$$